# How do I get prettier to stop escaping operators in JSX statements inside MDX files?

Tags: reactjs, prettier

I am attempting to reference a value and then multiply it by `100` within a JSX statement inside an MDX file:

```
{CFTWR["default"] * 100}
```

However, my company uses prettier to standardize the formatting of source code, and I am running into a problem I cannot find an answer for. Essentially, prettier is escaping the multiplication operator in the JSX statement above. I tried adding comments for prettier to ignore this block, but it doesn't work:

```
{/* prettier-ignore */}
{CFTWR["default"] \* 100}
```

I also tried to ignore the section, to no avail:

```
{/* prettier-ignore-start */}
{CFTWR["default"] \* 100}
{/* prettier-ignore-end */}
```

One thing that did work is adding a `<div>` element around the code block, but that causes my MDX plugin to think everything past the first line is javascript, and I would rather avoid that if possible. The file will process correctly, but it is annoying to work with.

[Example of syntax highlighting changing in the middle of my markdown text because the mdx plugin thinks it is now JSX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prwsE.png)

Anyone have a suggestion for how to get prettier to stop escaping my operators?

I attempted to resolve the issue using prettier-ignore statements, both within and without standard HTML tags. I also tried to isolate the JSX expression from my markdown text and apply the prettier-ignore statements that way.